# Similar names in a huge list

Tags: php, mysql, data-analysis

I have database of 50 000 + companies that is constantly updated (200+ per month).

The is a huge issue with repeated content because the **names** are not always strict/correct:
"Super 1 Store"
"Super One Store"
"Super 1 Stores"

**Edit**: another example .. which probably needs different approach:
"Amy's Pizza"  <---> "Organic Pizza by Amy and Company"

We need tool to scan the data for similar names.
I have some experience with [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) but they work nice for comparing if 2 strings are  similar ...
Here I have to scan  50 000 names  may be each-with-each and calculate there ... overall similarity rating ...

I need advice how to attack this problem the expected results is to have a list with 10-20 groups of very similar names, and may be further adjust the sensitivity for more results.

Comment: interesting! have you tried the `similar_text()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) ?

Comment: The easy answer is first normalize after map/reduce, but i suppose that you are looking for something more complex.

Comment: I have never used it but, how about SOUNDEX?

Comment: levenshtein, soundex and similar_text are more or less the same, with different algorithims

Comment: @mcuadros can you give an example ?

Comment: My method is "by hand", you must create your own rules to normalize the names, why the common variants, this will be the more accurate way, but with soundex/levenshtein will be the easy way.

Comment: If you can modify the interface used to insert new companies I suggest you to start by using hints to reduce (at least by a bit) the different names for the same company. After that working with similar_text/levenshtein/soundex should be something you should be doing every week/couple of weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem a year ago or so, and if i remember well, i solved (more or less) using `similar_text` and `soundex` as other people said in comments. Something like this:

```
<?php

$str1 = "Store 1 for you";
$str2 = "Store One 4 You";

similar_text(soundex($str1), soundex($str2), $percent);

if ($percent >= 66){
    echo "Equal";
    //Send an email for review
}else{
    echo "Different";
    //Proceed to insert in database
}
?>
```

In my case use a percent of 66% to determine the companies are the same (in this case do not insert into database but send an email to me to review, and check if is correct).

After some months with this solutions, i decide to use some kind of unique code for the companies (CIF in my case because is unique by company here in Spain).

Comment: This looks cool are the punctuation ""  ''  `  ignored in soundex ?
What about "Amy's Pizza" <-> "Organic Pizza by Amy and Company"... I think this is another type of problem

Comment: Yes, this works for lots of companies but not for all, this is why i send an email to myself to check if the comparison is correct. Sometimes i have to insert the companies manually this is why after a few months i change the registration and force to insert the CIF of the company so i can compare the CIF in bd and ensure the comany is the same or not.

Answer (score 1):

purely it depend on how much should we tolerate to consider 2 strings as similar.. soundex can be useful as well

```
select soundex('Super One Store') returns S165236
    select soundex('Super 1 Store'); returns S16236
    select soundex('Super One Stores') returns S1652362
```

S16236 IS COMMON IN ALL case , you can use filter like below

```
select * from (
select 'Super One Store' as c 
union
select 'Super 1 Store' as c
union
select 'Super One Stores' as c
union
select  'different one' as c
union 
select  'supers stores' as c
) tmp
where soundex(c) like CONCAT('%', soundex('Super store'), '%')
or soundex(c) like CONCAT('%', soundex('Super one store'), '%')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should go through that list of companies manually and create a table with a unique entry for each company. Then have a many-to-one table where you reference the different names to the correct company. I think this is what is meant by *normalization*.

Table: `companies`:

```
|id|base_name
|1 |Super 1 Store
```

Table: `company_mapping`:

```
|id|company_id|name
|1 |1         |Super 1 Store
|2 |1         |Super One Store
|3 |1         |Super 1 Stores
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not think that we have enough information about the OP's business in order to dictate that a computer task should be done manually.  Unless the business is using pre-printed forms, allowing the customer to hand write data will always end up as per the OP's situation.

Comment: @user2310289 I'm just saying that levenstein and soundex will probably give lots of erroneous results (two completely different companies that differ only by 2 letters) which still would require manual cleanup in one way or another.

Comment: Thinking of something like a magazine subscription business where the magazine contains a blank postcard for the user to fill in.  Unless the data entry program has the smarts, then levenstein and soundex and your approach will still fail.  If you can change your answer to reflect this I will upvote you.

Comment: @user2310289 Feel free to edit my answer as I don't quite understand what you're meaning.

Comment: Hello silkfire, I am meaning that I disagree that you are suggesting a  manual process.  There are no bounds for the stupidity of people, it can not be normalized.  Trying to coming up with (manually) a list of possible corruptions of a name is endless.